# Rails 5.2.3 to 6.0.0 upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Trying to upgrade Rails form 5.2.3 to 6.0.0 via **bundle update rails**, getting the following error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
In Gemfile:
rails (= 6.0.0)

devise-security was resolved to 0.14.2, which depends on
  rails (>= 4.2.0, < 7.0)

devise_token_auth was resolved to 1.1.0, which depends on
  rails (>= 4.2.0, < 6)
```

Comment: Did you add rails to gemfile like this? gem 'rails', '~> 6.0'

Comment: hi demir, yes as gem 'rails', '6.0.0'

Comment: hi John, what's your ruby version?

Comment: hi version 2.6.1

Comment: Have you tried the `bundle update` ?

Comment: What happens when you just add `gem "rails"` to gemfile and run the `bundle update` command?

Comment: yes, same error, both times

Comment: should not error. interesting :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the [`devise_token_auth`](https://rubygems.org/gems/devise_token_auth) gem in your application. The latest version of that is gem is `1.1.0` and that version doesn't support Ruby on Rails 6.0 yet. It still depends on
Rails `>= 4.2.0` and `< 6` (see the column in the middle of its [`Rubygems`](https://rubygems.org/gems/devise_token_auth/versions/1.1.0) page.

The fact that Rails released a new mayor version usually doesn't mean that all gem support that version on day one. Btw, this is the reason I always suggest keeping the number of used gems as low as possible and not to add a new gem dependency for every simple problem. And often we see that gems never get updated or very late.

In this case it looks like you are lucky because on `master` on GitHub this issue is already [solved](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/master/devise_token_auth.gemspec). That means the maintainer is aware of this issue and is working on it. You could choose to pull the gem directly from GitHub by changing the entry in your `Gemfile` to

```
gem 'devise_token_auth', github: 'lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth'
```

But keep in mind that that means you are basically using the latest alpha version all the time, and I would not recommend that on production. It might be a good idea to move forward updating your application, though.

Comment: Does this master branch on lynndylanhurley's repo support mongoid? I was using https://github.com/BunHouth/devise_token_auth and now needed to switch.

Comment: The latest version of the original gem supports Ruby on Rails up to the current version. No need to use lynndylanhurley's fork anymore.